# Changing infoWindow style in ArcGIS JavaScript API (v3.2)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, style

See below a screenshot of the `infoWindow`'s appearance in my ArcGIS JavaScript API (v3.2) application.

[image: default style]

As you can see the transparent title bar with the white buttons doesn't work too well against a background map with white areas.

I've used Chrome's developer tools to test changing the CSS of every element associated with the infoWindow but still haven't managed to stop it having a transparent background. The closest I've come gave it a coloured background - by adding a `background-color` to the `title` class - but this extended way outside the infoWindow and out of the map.

[image: altered title style]

How do I style this differently? Do I need to choose a new (non-claro) theme for the whole page? What are the other theme options?

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the html table and style the rows and columns according to ur choice.

Comment: Have you looked through the CSS file to see what is set to transparent? http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/esri/dijit/css/Popup.css

Comment: @Craig Chrome's developer tools show me every CSS style that applies to the elements. Transparency didn't seem to be mentioned, and I couldn't see any references to images that might be transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end my specific requirement - to remove transparency from the info window - was solved outside the ArcGIS JavaScript API.

The application's global CSS file defines a style for the class `.title` which includes `float: left;`

Because the info window uses the same class name I was getting some weird effects that were not related to API styling. The reason I couldn't find any mention of transparency in the CSS was because it wasn't a transparency setting making the area transparent, but instead an unwanted position offset that stopped it from being coloured.

I didn't want to change the global styling (or all titles in the site), and I wanted to avoid digging into the info window to change its title's class name, so I introduced the following JavaScript immediately after creating the map

```
var infoWindowTitle = query('.title', this.map.infoWindow.domNode)[0];
infoWindowTitle.style.float = 'none';
infoWindowTitle.style.styleFloat = 'none';  // IE
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post on this topic on the ArcGIS blog with specific directions on how to customize the look of a popup:  [Making Your Pop-up Pop!](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/08/15/making-your-pop-up-pop/)